# Spark Dataframe Select using Python list of columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Python list of columns

`col_list = [name, age, address.city, address.street, address.zipcode, address.state]` which I am using in Pyspark select.

```
df = df.select(*[col(c) for c in col_list]).alias(c.replace('.', '_'))
```

The above statement creates a flat dataframe with column names  - name, age, city, street, zipcode, state
but I need the column names like - address_city, address_street, address_zipcode, address_state.

Any suggestions.

Comment: `df.select(*[col(c).alias(c.replace('.', '_')) for c in col_list])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do,

```
df = df.select(*[F.col(c).alias(c.replace('.', '_')) for c in col_list])
```

Comment: @bdlogin If the solution works, consider accepting the answer